# Multivariate quasipolynomials and where to find them

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials

This question is inspired from thinking about David Speyer's [question about complex variable Ehrhart theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165884/is-there-an-ehrhart-polynomial-for-gaussian-integers).

In one variable, Ehrhart theory has been vastly generalized. For example it has been established that counting any set that can be defined in Presburger Arithmetic and a single parameter [is quasipolynomial](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.08520)! As a corollary, in David's question, the counting function is a quasipolynomial when we specialize the value of one of the variables.

The multiparameter version of Ehrhart theory is bound to get a bit trickier. For example the number of lattice points in the segment between $(s,0)$ and $(0,t)$ is $1+\gcd(s,t)$. This function is a quasipolynomial when you specialize either value, but it is not a quasipolynomial in both variables, meaning that there is no integer $N$ so that when restricting $s,t$ to residue classes $(\text{mod } N)$ we get a polynomial in $s,t$.

My question is motivated from a basic property of polynomials (what Richard Palais calls [analogs of Hartog's theorem](http://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/AnalogsOfHartogsTheorem.pdf)): If a multivariate function is a polynomial of bounded degree in each variable separately, then it is a multivariable polynomial.

**Question:** Can we describe bivariate functions that are quasipolynomial of bounded degree in each variable? Are they bivariate quasipolynomials plus perhaps linear combinations of terms like $\gcd(P,Q)$, for bivariate polynomials $P,Q$?

Answer (score 5):

There is a multivariate version of an Ehrhart quasipolynomial (but it is necessarily only piecewise defined). Namely, fix an integer matrix **A**, the number of integer lattice points in the rational polytope { **x** : **Ax** ≤ **b** } is a piecewise-defined quasipolynomials in the components of **b** (viewed as an integer vector). Geometrically, what we're doing is fixing the normal vectors of a set of (possible) facets of a polytope and then vary the position of the facets. (Note that in your example, the normals are not preserved.)

It is a short step (using slack variables) to convert ≤ into =, and then the counting function above goes by the name of *vector partition function* (associated with A). See [this seminal paper by Dahmen & Micchelli](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-308-02/S0002-9947-1988-0951619-X/home.html) as a starting point.